# Take a screenshot of the scrollable area of a Windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot of the whole of a Windows 8 App? The area is larger than the height of the screen, so I want the full scrollable area.

I've tried:

- Snipping Tool
- [Ducklink](http://www.ducklink.com/) tool
- Combinations of <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>
- Snagit 12
- Windows 8 Visual Studio Simulator

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot of an image larger than the screen](http://superuser.com/questions/295938/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-an-image-larger-than-the-screen)

Comment: I have used SnagIt to capture Windows 7 application scrolling contents. Have not tested with Win8. http://www.techsmith.com/snagit-features.html

Comment: @duDE this question is specific to Windows 8 "Metro" apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)

It can capture Vertical and Horizontal scrolling area and also has a bunch of uyseful features for screenshot modification.

[Capture a Scrolling Window](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-snagit-mac-scrolling-window.html)

Comment: Snagit doesn't seem to work on Metro apps

Comment: You're right, the scroll doesn't work on Metro apps. I've missed that as the question didn't mention Metro.

Comment: we're not allowed to use the word "Metro" now remember :-)

Comment: That mislead me :)