# Create a virtual resolution like on Matrox cards?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, virtual-desktop, amd-graphics-card

Back then on a Matrox G400 one was able to create a virtual resolution.

Example:

- screen is 800x600
- virtual resolution is set to 1600x600
- then when moving horizontally with the mouse, you 'scroll' to the part you're interested in

(taskbar was twice as wide obviously, not a problem for me)

(I need to take screenshots larger than my LCD panel is)

**Question:**

Is there a software for doing the same on Windows 10 and an AMD GPU ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take a screenshot of a window larger than the screen](https://superuser.com/questions/295938/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-window-larger-than-the-screen)

Comment: The VMware approach is a very good option, thanks !!!